# Can Patch SUPEE-8167 be installed on older Magento 1.9 version?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8167

I am on an **older version of Magento**. Can the **patch still be applied** even on an old version or does it need to be on 1.9?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Paypal with instant notification you can apply this patch.

First, understand the Magento released `SUPEE 8167`, It is `IPN patch`, PayPal will start using HTTPS URL (secured) for IPN communication. Currently, they are accepting HTTP requests.

For sure take backup of `app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\ipn.php` Patch only changes above file.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can download and install the patch for Magento versions between 1.5-1.9.

Download here:`https://magento.com/tech-resources/download`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Paypal on magento ver 1.x  but not payment instant notification. then you don't need to add patch as According to paypal if you don't use Paypal IPN, "NO ACTION IS REQUIRED".

click for more details: http://www.programmingsimplified.in/2017/06/how-to-install-paypal-security-patch.html